# Set expire date on cookie with npm store.js package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, cookies

I'm using "[store](https://www.npmjs.com/package/store)" to handle my cookies, It all works great, except that I can't figure out how to set an expire date, I'd like to set it for one day

I've tried following the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/store#make-your-own-build) but it doesn't seem to work

I imported and set the store like the documentation said:

```
var storages = [
    require('store/storages/localStorage'),
    require('store/storages/cookieStorage')
]
var plugins = [
    require('store/plugins/defaults'),
    require('store/plugins/expire')
]
var store = engine.createStore(storages, plugins) 

let expire_date = new Date().getTime() + 86400000;
store.set('livePreview', true, expire_date);
```

**EDIT**: I have also tried this:

```
import store from 'store'
var expirePlugin = require('store/plugins/expire')
store.addPlugin(expirePlugin)

let expire_date = new Date().getTime() + 86400000;
store.set('livePreview', true, expire_date);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add the code showing how you create the store

Comment: @jamomani sorry, I update the question

Comment: Cookies should be string values, you are using a boolean. Have you tried changing that?

Comment: If I look at my dev console, and go to the application tab, I can see that it's stored in my "local storage" and not my 'cookies', in my local storage I have a key (__storejs_expire_mixin_livePreview) with the value (1596801156330). But it still doesn't get deleted after the given time

Comment: Have you tried what happens if you remove this line require('store/storages/localStorage'),` or move it after the cookie plugin?

Comment: That was indeed to problem for it being stored in localstorage, now I have 2 cookies set. 1: **name:** livePreview, **value:** 'true', **Expires / Max-Age:** "Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT" and 2.: **name:** __storejs_expire_mixin_livePreview, **value:**"1596801944838", **Expires / Max-Age:**"Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07 GMT"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219405/discussion-between-yorbjorn-and-jamomani).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this line `require('store/storages/localStorage')` or move it after the cookie plugin.